# error: failed to discover supported resources kubernetes google cloud platform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I was performing a practical where i was deploying a containerised sample application using kubernetes.

i was trying to run container on google cloud platform using kubernetes engine.But while deploying container using "kubectl run" command using google cloud shell.

its showing an error "***error: failed to discover supported resources: Get https://35.240.145.231/apis/extensions/v1beta1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority***".

From Error, i can recollect that its because of "SSL Certificate" not authorised.

I even exported the config file resides at "***$HOME/.kube/config***". but still getting the same error.

please anyone help me understand the real issue behind this.

Best,

Swapnil Pawar

Comment: can you run "gcloud container clusters get-credentials [cluster_name] --zone [cluster_zone]" to make sure that you have the correct credentials to interact with the GKE API?

Answer (score 6):

You may try following steps,

1. List all the available clusters,

   ```
   $ gcloud container clusters list
   ```
2. Depending upon how you have configured the cluster, if the cluster location is configured for a specific zone then,

   ```
   $ gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --ZONE <location>
   ```

   or if the location is configured for a region then,

   ```
   $ gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --REGION <location>
   ```

The above command will update your kubectl config file **$HOME/.kube/config**

3. Now, the tricky part.
   If you have more than one cluster that you have configured, then your **$HOME/.kube/config** will have two or more entries. You can verify it by doing a **cat** command on the config file.

To select a particular context/cluster, you need to run the following commands

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts -o=name // will give you a list of available contexts

$ kubectl config use-context <CONTEXT_NAME>

$ kubectl config set-context <CONTEXT_NAME>
```

Now, you may run the kubectl run.